# Trying to concatenate a string with a int but the min() command is there and is causing mayhem

Tags: python

Im trying to do something for a school project and have the code ask the users for some numbers then print the smallest from the bunch.The main issue with this is that i have to put a string with the print so that the grading system gives a 100.Im not sure on how to do that with my knowledge.Here is my code-

```
num1=int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2=int(input("Enter a number: "))
num3=int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(min("Smallest:", num1 , num2 , num3))
```

and the error message-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

I have tried making the variables strings like such-

```
num1=int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2=int(input("Enter a number: "))
num3=int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(min("Smallest:", str(num1 , num2 , num3)))
```

and even just having the str() command with each variable but it doesn't like my attempt to fix it.

Comment: I really liked how you solved that.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hello @NindeBonic in order to show the Smallest number, you need to delete the `"Smallest"` string that you are trying to concat, instead use:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter a number: "))

# print the minumum of the three numbers
print("Smallest: ", min(num1, num2, num3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This has solved it.

Answer (score -1):

```
num1=int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2=int(input("Enter a number: "))
num3=int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("Smallest: " + str(min(num1 , num2 , num3)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.